# Siege not hitting Heroku Apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, benchmarking, siege

I'm using Siege to do some basic load testing on my app. I've tried it out locally and it works great when I'm running my webapp on `localhost:3000`.

However whenever I try running it on my production environment (Rails app hosted on Heroku), it produces no results -

```
> siege -d2 -r3 -c2 -if urls.txt --header="Referer: /log_in"
** SIEGE 3.1.4
** Preparing 2 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
done.

Transactions:              0 hits
Availability:           0.00 %
Elapsed time:           5.45 secs
Data transferred:         0.00 MB
Response time:            0.00 secs
Transaction rate:         0.00 trans/sec
Throughput:           0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:            0.00
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:             6
Longest transaction:          0.00
Shortest transaction:         0.00

LOG FILE: /usr/local/var/siege.log
You can disable this log file notification by editing
/Users/jeeves/.siege/siege.conf and changing 'show-logfile' to false.
```

As you can see it made 0 hits. I can also confirm in the app log that no requests reached the server.

The only difference between the local and hosted environments is the use of `https://` for SSL and the fact that it's being routed through DNS and other Heroku routing.

The log file also provides no information or error. Another StackOverflow post suggested setting the `proxy-host` and `proxy-port`, but I'm not really familiar with what those do and how they might relate to Heroku.

As a side note, the only real thing I changed in my `.siegerc` config file was the addition of one line to allow my requests to authenticate -

```
    login-url = https://foo.example.co/auth/example/callback?email=jeeves%40example.co&password=blueSUN
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** - here's my entire siege config file. It's pretty much the stock template and the only thing changed from the default is the `login-url` mentioned above - http://pastebin.com/JuA9MUG2

Comment: please post your .siegerc file, redacted.

Comment: Updated the post with the siegerc file